# Android auto - will sound play to car speakers if played from app

Tags: android, android-auto

I have some sound that plays during a phone call on my app. Its hard to test this on the desktop head unit but i'd like to know on a real device if i simply plug the phone into the car will my audio automatically play to the car speakers ? I notice when i use the DHU that it already sets the phone on speaker so im assuming it routes to the cars speakers but i wanted to make sure.

So to be clear, imagine i have an app that plays music based on some trigger, if i plug the phone into the car and execute that trigger will the audio get routed to the speakers of the car without the app needing to do anything ?

Comment: why didn't you try it? dont have the real device? dont have a speaker? dont have a car?

Comment: i dont have  that type of car.  It seems like it would work but i wanted confidence.

Answer (score 3):

I plugged my phone into my Pioneey NEX head unit and the only audio that came through the head unit was that of the applications that support Android Auto.  Any additional sounds (e.g. notifications not associated to an Android Auto application) were played by the phone itself.

Hope this helps.

dave